# Looping dates with dayjs

Tags: javascript, dayjs

I am moving from moment() to dayjs(). I have a loop that creates an array of objects. This loop works in moment but not in dayjs. I am guessing this is because dayjs is Immutable.

Works fine :

```
    let getMonths = () => {
    let months = []
    let s = moment().startOf('year')
    let e = moment().endOf('year')

    for (var m = moment(s); m.isBefore(dayjs(e)); m.add(1, 'month')) {
        months.push({ id: m.format('MM'), value: m.format('MMM') });
    }
    return months;
}
```

Fails :

```
    let getMonths = () => {
    let months = []
    let s = dayjs().startOf('year')
    let e = dayjs().endOf('year')

    for (var m = dayjs(s); m.isBefore(dayjs(e)); m.add(1, 'month')) {
        months.push({ id: m.format('MM'), value: m.format('MMM') });
    }
    return months;
}
```

I need to refactor for dayjs
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `dayjs(m).isBefore(e)` or `m.isBefore(e.format())` to compare two dayjs objects.

```
let getMonths = () => {
    let months = []
    let s = dayjs().startOf('year')
    let e = dayjs().endOf('year')

    for (var m = dayjs(s); m.isBefore(e); m = m.add(1, 'month')) {
        months.push({ id: m.format('MM'), value: m.format('MMM') });
    }
    return months;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

X/Y problem. What is the actual need you have?

This?

```
[{ "id": "01", "value":"Jan" }, 
 { "id": "02", "value":"Feb" },
```

Why use any framework?

```js
// Added value - translate for free

const getMonths = locale => {
  const format = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, { "month": 'short' }).format;
  const start = new Date(2020, 0, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0); // arbitrary 
  return  Array.from({ length: 12 })
    .map((_, month) => ({
      "id": String(month + 1).padStart(2, "0"),
      "value": format(start.setMonth(month))
    }));
};
console.log(getMonths('en-GB'));
console.log(getMonths('da-DK'));
```

Comment: Great thanks, think you've answered my question whether to move from moment.js to a new framework or use vanilla